# Can neither enter nor reeinstall Windows7 Starter

Tags: windows-7, bios

So the actual problem is that when starting Windows, instead of getting showed the awailable user-accounts and being allowed to enter the password, i am asked to enter a username and a password (although i didnt set any password), and also the BIOS do not recognize the external DVD-drive anymore!

What i did:

I want to sell my old netbook, so i wanted to reinstall the system i baught with it, which was win7 starter, instead of windows7 ultimate i used myself and which i wanted to keep for the new one.

Now, because there are no installation DVD's for win7 starter, i first tried just to reinstall ultimate and enter the key, it didnt work and didnt tell me to downgrade or something.

Then i read about a way Modyfying the DVD so it is able to install win7 starter too. So i modyfyied the ISO, burned it to a new DVD and reinstalled win7 starter.

(I'm not shure, but i may have reinstalled it again for some reason)

and this is where we are.

Thank you in advance for every Help!

Comment: Your question needs some improvement from you. In it's current state it seems to be [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Unless you wiped out the recovery partition on the disk there will be a way to bring up a recovery menu that includes an option to "Factory Restore" or something similarly named. The exact method and dialogs vary with the manufacturer and laptop model